# How to show GeoJson feature properties as labels on the angular leaflet map?

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm trying to show GeoJson feature properties as labels on the leaflet map.
here's my code:

```
private createGeoJsonLayer(cords) {
return L.geoJSON(
  cords as any,
  {
    onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
      layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.country_name).openTooltip();
    },
  });
```

the problem with this code is that it depends on the mouse hover to show the tooltip and the tooltip does not open when the page loads, how can I fix this? user expects to see all the country names as labels when the page loads.

and if there is a better way than tooltip to show labels on the map, I'll be happy to hear that.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tooltip-permanent , https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layer-bindtooltip

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to improve my own code around labels like you.
This is a piece of my code, similar to yours, that I'm working on over a previous ajax call.

In this case the tooltip always open when the page loads. The Leaflet documentation explains about parameters like "permanent: true":

> Whether to open the tooltip permanently or only on mouseover.

So"true" is necessary in your case.

It is working, and could be helpful for you.

```
var calzada = new L.geoJson(data, {
                    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                      layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.nam.toString(), 
                         {permanent: true, className: 'label'}
                        ).addTo(map);
                    }
                  })
```

"nam" is the property I am labeling and "label" is my CSS style

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).